# How do Perl if-statements work under the hood?

Tags: perl, perlguts

How does Perl's interpreter do if-statements? I wanted to *try* to implement a simple [Lazy-Basic-Block-Versioning](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.0352) for if-statements that use `ref` as a predicate, and maybe subsequently for sub-routines as well.

After studying the source code I see OP codes for everything but control flow. My interpreter experience is quite limited, but I would assume to see a `OP_IF` that would pop the stack for it's predicates OP codes or something along those lines. I found `KEY_if` which comes from the Yacc grammar, which then subsequently is used in `toke.c` and translated to a `KW_IF`, but I can't find where `KW_IF` is actually used.

I originally intended to just add some basic optimization with global state to `peep.c`, but since there is no `OP_IF` I'm struggling to see the big-picture of how control flow is handled.

Comment: If you're doing this for practical reasons, more power to you. But if you're trying to cut your teeth on language design, hacking at _Perl_ is probably one of the worst choices for a learning tool. A nice, consistent Lisp dialect or something homoiconic like Io would probably serve that purpose better.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo It's mostly to get more comfortable with the Perl internals. So I would call it practical, thanks for the insights though.

Comment: Re "*It's mostly to get more comfortable with the Perl internals.*", `-MO=Concise,-exec` and Devel::Peek's `Dump` are your friends.

Comment: There was some documentation named "illguts". The source of it is still obtainable, but I don't know if the generated documents are? Goes into the details of variables.

Comment: Honestly, knowledge of the parser (as opposed to its output, viewable with Concise) isn't really useful. I've never even looked at it.

Comment: @ikegami At least there is a web page [PerlGuts Illustrated](http://blob.perl.org/tpc/1998/Perl_Language_and_Modules/Perl%20Illustrated/) (there used to be a pdf as well?).  And then there's perldoc's [perlguts](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlguts)

Comment: ... and here's a pdf for it, on cpan: [illguts](https://www.cpan.org/authors/id/G/GA/GAAS/illguts-0.09.pdf).  This is labeled as version `0.09`, while the web page (linked above in my previous comment) is `0.06`

Comment: @zdim, Those are both ancient. [Version 0.49](https://metacpan.org/release/RURBAN/illguts-0.49) is the latest. [repo](https://github.com/rurban/illguts)

Comment: The repo comes with a Makefile which I used to package it all, with a `pdf` and an `index.html`.  A link on Google Drive: [perl-illguts-0.49](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1C4Dl1HD617dlOu2noyh0ic_xY7lBtZ-U?usp=drive_link)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`if` gets compiled into an `and` or `or` op.

```bash
perl -MO=Concise,-exec -e'if ( f() ) { ... }'
```

```
1  <0> enter v
2  <;> nextstate(main 1 -e:1) v:{
3  <0> pushmark s
4  <#> gv[*f] s/EARLYCV
5  <1> entersub[t2] sKS/TARG
6  <|> and(other->7) vK/1
7      <0> pushmark s
8      <$> const[PV "Unimplemented"] s
9      <@> die vK/1
a  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC
-e syntax OK
```

```bash
perl -MO=Concise,-exec -e'if ( !f() ) { ... }'
```

```
1  <0> enter v
2  <;> nextstate(main 1 -e:1) v:{
3  <0> pushmark s
4  <#> gv[*f] s/EARLYCV
5  <1> entersub[t2] sKS/TARG
6  <|> or(other->7) vK/1
7      <0> pushmark s
8      <$> const[PV "Unimplemented"] s
9      <@> die vK/1
a  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC
-e syntax OK
```

`if` can also be compiled into a `cond_expr` op like the conditional operator (`?:`).

```bash
perl -MO=Concise,-exec -e'if ( f() ) { ... } else { ... }'
```

```
1  <0> enter v
2  <;> nextstate(main 1 -e:1) v:{
3  <0> pushmark s
4  <#> gv[*f] s/EARLYCV
5  <1> entersub[t2] sKS/TARG
6  <|> cond_expr(other->7) vK/1
7      <0> pushmark s
8      <$> const[PV "Unimplemented"] s
9      <@> die vK/1
           goto a
b  <0> enter v
c  <;> nextstate(main 5 -e:1) v
d  <0> pushmark s
e  <$> const[PV "Unimplemented"] s
f  <@> die vK/1
g  <@> leave vKP
a  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC
-e syntax OK
```

The opcode `name` from Concise maps to a function named `pp_name` in `pp*.c` (with a few exceptions).

Comment: Remove the `,-exec` to see the unflattened representation.

Comment: Further, for an if with an else clause, then it compiles to an OP_COND_EXPR, which is the same op that implements $cond ? $val1 : $val2.